# How can I edit firewall rules inside of a GPO using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I know how to edit firewall rules via powershell on a local machine. How can I go about editing firewall rules that are specified in an group policy?

I know I can just edit them via GPMC, but I am looking to change some remote addresses in bulk on a particular firewall rule

This is for 2012R2.

I am trying to use the open-netgpo command, but get this....

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop> $gpoSession = Open-NetGPO –PolicyStore lab.domain.edu\WindowsNetSysBaseFirewallPolicy
Open-NetGPO : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:15
+ $gpoSession = Open-NetGPO –PolicyStore lab.brandeis.edu\WindowsNetSysBaseFirewal ...
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetGPO:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetGPO) [Open-NetGPO], CimExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,Open-NetGPO
```

What is going on here? Am I missing something? This should be pretty straight forward. This is an elevated powershell session on the domain controller itself.

Other GPO's throw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if the GPO name is wrong, so in this case, `WindowsNetSysBaseFirewallPolicy` probably doesn't exist.